# Why do some F1 engineers sit in the garage and some sit on the pit wall?

Tags: formula-1

I watch Formula 1 races, especially between Mercedes and Red Bull. At the 2021 Spanish GP, there was a tense battle between Lewis and Max. What I found interesting is that Bono (Lewis' engineer) was inside the Mercedes garage, while GP (Max's engineer) was outside on the pit wall.

**Why were the race engineers put in different spots?**

Bono sitting in the garage:
[image: Mercedes race engineer Pete "Bono" Bonnington sitting in the garage]

GP sitting on the pit wall:
[image: Red Bull race engineer Gianpiero "GP" Lambiase sitting on the pit wall]

Comment: They have to be somewhere!  Why do you think it matters where they sit?